GAIN in Sextractor
I'm using SExtractor for source detection from JWST CEERS NIRCam images. I'm using the fully reduced mosaics provided in CEERS website (The mosaics are on pixel scales of 0.03"/pix and are pixel-aligned across all filters. The science images are in units of MegaJansky per steradian (MJy/sr)) . Since my images are in units of MJy/sr I thought of using 0 for GAIN parameter. But it seems that flux_err is using GAIN in its calculation (https://sextractor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Photom.html) 
What value should I give for GAIN for source extraction from my images ?

GAIN in SExtractor has the usual meaning of electrons/ADU (ADU = analog-to-digital units, aka "counts"). SExtractor assumes the pixel values are in ADUs, which is why it wants to know the gain value, so it can convert them into electrons/pixel and then make noise estimates based on the usual Gaussian approximation to Poisson noise. (SExtractor also estimates background noise from directly measured pixel-to-pixel variations, something for which the gain is unnecessary.)
If you tell SExtractor the gain is 0, then you are saying that all pixels have values of 0 electrons. Which is obviously nonsense. (Plus, as you can see, you'll get division-by-zero errors.)
If you want really correct errors, then I think you need to figure out how to convert the image values back into ADU/pixel before running SExtractor, and use the correct GAIN value for the instrument. Or (more or less equivalently) figure out the numerical transformation from electrons/pixel to MJy/sr for those images, and use that as the "gain".
Failing that, I'd suggest setting GAIN = 1, and just accept that the flux errors will be somewhat wrong.

I would require a correct error for my science case. As you mentioned the conversion factor for JWST NIRCAM I saw as (NIRCam images in units of MJy/sr are derived from data rate images (rate.fits), in units of counts/s  (DN/s). The conversion factor is stored in the FITS header under the PHOTMJSR, keyword, which has units of (MJy/sr) / (DN/s)) (https://jwst-docs.stsci.edu/jwst-near-infrared-camera/nircam-performance/nircam-absolute-flux-calibration-and-zeropoints#gsc.tab=0)

Can I use this PHOTMJSR for GAIN or
Will it be dependent on the EXPOSURE TIME also . 'XPOSURE = 5669.016000000001 / [s] Effective exposure time' and 'PHOTMJSR= 0.4907999932765961 / Flux density (MJy/steradian) producing 1 cps' for a particular filter (XPOSURE/PHOTMJSR will be a very big value)

You want a conversion that turns MJr/sr into total electrons, so you need to use PHOTMJSR and the exposure time and the actual A/D gain of the detector (which, according to this], is about 2.0).

Thank you for the reply again. But I am not getting it. multiplying them will be a very large value right?

It’s a cumulative exposure time of over an hour and a half on a 6.5m telescope; you should probably expect large values.

Okay , Thank you . So  I can  use GAIN = XPOSURE / (PHOTMJSR * detector gain) which comes around 5772 for this case ?

It would be GAIN = detector_gain * XPOSURE / PHOTMJSR .

Thanks.
My images are in units of MJy/sr , yet why are my sextractor output showing that it is in units of count.
'#  11 FLUX_APER              Flux vector within fixed circular aperture(s)              [count]'
which means , I have to do a conversion here again into flux in Jy ?
Flux (Jy)=(FLUX_APER (counts)×PHOTMJSR (MJy/sr)×10e−6)/XPOSURE (s)
​

SExtractor doesn't know about flux or surface-brightness values; it only knows about pixel values in the data array, which it assumes are cumulative ADUs. (If you supply a magnitude zero point, then it will also calculate magnitudes, but that's about it.)

Note that MJy/sr are surface brightness units, so your conversion needs to account for the pixel area in sr.

Okay. For getting the AB magnitude I am providing the zeropoint.
So for the conversion of flux , I can use flux_aper(mjy) = flux_aper(count) * PHOTMJSR*PIXAR_SR
(where PIXAR_SR is the  Nominal pixel area in steradians and PHOTMJSR is the flux density (MJy/steradian) producing 1 cps)
